# how to use toFixed() in a function for calculating

Tags: jquery, tofixed

I am using this script for realtime calculating a price between span tags:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var form = $('.bestelformulier'),
    elements = form.find('[data-price], [type="radio"], [type="checkbox"], select'),
    totalEl = $('.totaalprijs');


//function to calculate total
var calculateTotal = function () {
    var total = 0;

    $.each(elements, function () {
        var field = $(this),
            newVal;

       // swith type omitted

        newVal = parseFloat(newVal);
        total += newVal;
    });

    totalEl.text(total);
};

// bind events
elements.on('change keyup', calculateTotal);
});
```

The price is displayed in:

```
<span class="totaalprijs"></span>
```

Where do I have to put:

```
toFixed(2)
```

So that the price always shows 2 decimals?

Comment: `newVal` is undefined. Did you leave out some code?

Comment: `totalEl.text(total.toFixed(2))`?

Comment: `totalEl.text(total.toFixed(2))`  did the job! THank you